# Desperate Help Needed on media recorder

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple camcorder application using mediarecorder. The program keeps crashing and I get errors when I call `prepare` on the mediarecorder.

Layout Below
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/camera_layout" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <android.view.SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </android.view.SurfaceView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/start_video" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Start Video">
    </Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/stop_video" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Stop Video"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/start_video">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code Below
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class start extends Activity 
{
    private SurfaceView preview;
    private SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
    private String locationName;
    private String filepath;
    private File video;

    public void onCreate(Bundle videocawk) {
        super.onCreate(videocawk);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
        setSurface();
        //locationName = getIntent().getStringExtra("locationName");
        locationName = "dan";
        filepath = getFilePath(locationName);
        try {
            MediaRecorder r = getMediaRecorder(filepath, previewHolder.getSurface());
            setButtonListeners(r);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getFilePath(String locName) {
        String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        String add = "/vext/";
        String name = locName + " -- 1";
        String total = dir + add + name;
        video = new File(total);
        return total;
    }

    private void setSurface() {
        preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    private void setButtonListeners(final MediaRecorder r) {
        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_video);
        Button end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_video);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startRecording(r);

            }
        });

        end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopRecording(r);
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    private void startRecording(MediaRecorder r) {
        r.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording(MediaRecorder r) {
        r.stop();
    }

    private MediaRecorder getMediaRecorder(String filepath, Surface s)
            throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        MediaRecorder m_recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        m_recorder.setPreviewDisplay(s);
        m_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        m_recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        m_recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        m_recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        m_recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        m_recorder.setMaxDuration(20000); // length of video in MS
        m_recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
        m_recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
        m_recorder.setOutputFile(video.getPath());
        m_recorder.prepare();

        return m_recorder;
    }

}
```

The errors I get are:

> 07-18 19:43:40.044: ERROR/audio_input(987): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
> 07-18 19:43:40.044: ERROR/audio_input(987): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
>
> 07-18 19:43:40.044: ERROR/CameraInput(987): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
>
> 07-18 19:43:40.044: ERROR/CameraInput(987): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0

Answer (score 0):

Check out [issue 5063](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5063) on Android's bug tracker

Answer (score 0):

Dan,
  does your logcat contain something like the following right after the prepare?

```
I/DEBUG   (20354): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (20354): Build fingerprint: 'vendor/inc/inc/inc:2.1-update1/ERE/2222:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (20354): pid: 20392, tid: 20392  >>> com.xyzzy.test <<<
I/DEBUG   (20354): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000078
I/DEBUG   (20354):  r0 ffffe711  r1 ffffe700  r2 418b8528  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (20354):  r4 ab309358  r5 0000aa90  r6 bee6d818  r7 4186bc6c
I/DEBUG   (20354):  r8 bee6d830  r9 4186bc64  10 bee6d958  fp 4186bc60
```

If so, this segfault may be related to timing issues with the MediaRecorder state machine.  The trick (apparently) is to ensure that there is a sufficient (hardware specific?) delay after the configuration, and before the prepare.

See a discussion here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5050

Comment: PS.  i forgot to say, it may be that the unsupported params are red herrings - some people have reported recording sucessfully in spite of them.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5063 has the correct solution. Make sure to add the following lines to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And then call

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
recorder.reset();
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA); 
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
```